# How to restart Java with a specific argument?

Tags: centos, java

While running my Minecraft server, I noticed the following message outputted in the console.

```
24.01 02:11:04 [Server] INFO Warning, your max perm gen size is not set or less than 128mb.
It is recommended you restart Java with the following argument: -XX:MaxPermSize=128M
```

I was wondering what exactly the max perm gen size is, and more importantly, how can I restart Java via command line with this argument? I tried searching for how to restart Java, but there does not seem to be any documentation on how to do this via command line.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> PermGen space is used for things that do not change (or change often).
>   e.g. Java classes.  So often large, complex apps will need lots of
>   PermGen space.

Source: http://rimuhosting.com/knowledgebase/linux/java/-Xmx-settings

If minecraft is started with a shell script, look for a line that looks something like this:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

Add a new java configuration setting for the max perm size:

```
java -Xmx1024M -Xms1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=128M -jar minecraft_server.jar nogui
```

Comment: Additional resources related to PermGen: http://plumbr.eu/blog/what-is-a-permgen-leak & http://www.cooljeff.co.uk/2009/11/01/garbage-collection-of-the-permanent-generation-permgen/